# asp.net RowFilter comparing string with int

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012

Im having an issue with this , Im new to asp.net and really dont have much understanding with their syntax, I do understand the error but have no idea how to implement a fix:

```
   ProductTable.RowFilter = "ProductID ='" & ddlCategory.SelectedValue & "'"
```

The error im recieving is **:** *cannot perform '=' operation on system.int32 and system.string data view*

my productID data type is **:** *int*;

Now i dont see how im comparing a string vs int, ddlCatergory selected index would also return a value... besides the point...im completely stuck.

any help is appreciated.

Using windows 8,  VS 2012 , SQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ddlCategory.SelectedValue` is likely to be `string` given the `SelectedValue` attribute of the drop down list is a `string`, you are also assigning it as a string e.g. the filter value could end up being something like `"ProductID ='123'"` where 123 is the `SelectedValue`.

Assuming that `SelectedValue` is never null or empty I would use something like:

```
ProductTable.RowFilter = string.format("ProductID = {0}", ddlCategory.SelectedValue);
```

If it could be empty then I would do something along these lines:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlCategory.SelectedValue))
{
    ProductTable.RowFilter ="";
}
else {
    ProductTable.RowFilter = string.format("ProductID = {0}", ddlCategory.SelectedValue);
}
```

OR

```
int tempInt;
if(int.TryParse(ddlCategory.SelectedValue,out tempInt))
{        
    ProductTable.RowFilter = string.format("ProductID = {0}", tempInt);
}
```

I've written the above in C# (not syntax checked though sorry!) though it would be easy enough to convert it to VB if necessary.

Comment: lol, syntax issue after operator aswell, Im thinking the same thing but i program in php and have no idea about asp.net, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You should try by removing single quotes after = sign, so it give something like this

```
 ProductTable.RowFilter = "ProductID = " + ddlCategory.SelectedValue
```

Comment: Couldnt get this to work, syntax error after operator. Im thinking this should work aswell, i will get back to you if i work something out